# For Monerujo, is writing to internal storage or to an SD card better for phone longevity?

Tags: mobile

I was wondering if the frequent writing to the wallet file(s) would be better suited to an SD card rather than to internal phone storage. My reasoning is that if the SD card goes bad to due to the number of writes, it can be replaced with relatively minimal expense. However, if the internal storage goes bad due to the number of writes in syncing wallet files, the entire phone would need to be replaced.

Of course, there are other applications on the phone which write to internal storage. I was wondering if phone life could be increased by writing to a SD card rather than internal storage, or if it makes much of a difference.